# Edit CodePipeline that applies terraform code

Tags: terraform, cicd, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

We have all AWS resources managed in a CodeCommit repository with terraform. This includes the CodePipeline that performs an actual deployment of changed terraform code. Is it possible to safely update that pipeline by modifying involved terraform code without manual `apply` outside of the automation?

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-edit.html),

> If a revision is running through your pipeline when you save your changes, the run is not completed.

I don't think that any code is worth posting here. The pipeline has a Source step (retrieving repository contents) followed by two stages of the same shape:

> plan (CodeBuild) -> manual review -> apply (CodeBuild)

There are two such stages for separate components (say, shared infra like PR validation, and then staging/production environment - staging and production are deployed via separate pipelines to ensure access separation). Terraform pipeline belongs to the second stage.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the issue. If you want to make changes to the code pipeline and not affect the existing state/resources, you need to look at the trigger for your pipeline.
A good practice is to only configure the launch of the pipeline if .tf file are changed.

Comment: Yes, it only fires when tf repository gets a PR to dev/master merged, of course. So, if I change the tf code that defines this pipeline and merge these changes, I want these changes to be applied, right? If I run that through pipeline (and it will happen automatically with the help of trigger, as with any other PR-driven pipeline), the pipeline modifies itself - and thus current (applying) run may be cancelled, breaking the deployment. Why "not affect the existing state/resources"? The tf pipeline is in state and is a resource, it must be changed... @Lauden

Comment: To reiterate, I have terraform code that defines a pipeline. This pipeline deploys that terraform code (chicken&egg problem already solved by applying outside of CI once initially). If I change the pipeline code, it should still be applied in CI - but AWS docs state that pipeline run is cancelled when any modifications are made. How to break this loop?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The easiest way would be to apply the changes to the pipeline outside of CI.

Comment: @Lauden it's far from "easy" indeed: once more than a couple of devs have to touch the codebase, we'll have to add a CI step testing for that (denying PRs where `plan` changes this pipeline), do something with access (we don't usually use admin credentials allowing arbitrary modifications on dev machines - that sounds really scary). Also we have to be absolutely sure that changes not related to this pipeline are not applying locally - probably involving `terraform apply -target`, which is also a bit scary due to inconsistent state possibility.

Comment: The best I managed to invent is "if there are modifications for deployment pipeline, skip pipeline execution and run in single CodeBuild without manual approval step", but this relies on "nothing will change between `plan` emitted during PR validation and `apply` step" and adds considerable complexity to the workflow